# Updating Tkinter display when database information changes?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am currently working on a project for university with a raspberry pi where some information from a table is displayed on through Tkinter.

The program Queries the database for a AreaActive when first starting up and sets a Tkinter label to display some data from one of the columns if true.

However if I start the application and the ActiveActive is not found it displays 'None found' Code for querying the database can be found below:

```
#Creating the cursor
cursor = db.cursor()
#search the database to to look for active area
sql = "SELECT * From User Where AreaActive = '%s'" % ('Yes')

try:
cursor.execute(sql)

results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    user_ID = row[0]
    UserEmail = row[1]
    UserPassword = row[2]
    AreaActive = row[3]
    NoteHeading = row[4]
    NoteContent = row[5]
    PubNoteHeading = row[6]
    PubNoteContent = row[7]
    TextSize = row[8]
    Calapi = row[9]

print "user_ID=%d, UserEmail=%s, UserPassword=%s, AreaActive=%s, NoteHeading=%s, NoteContent=%s, PubNoteHeading=%s, PubNoteContent=%s, TextSize=%d, Calapi=%s" % \
(user_ID, UserEmail, UserPassword, AreaActive, NoteHeading, NoteContent, PubNoteHeading, PubNoteContent, TextSize, Calapi)

#error if no results found
except:

NoteHeading = 'None found'
NoteContent = 'None found'
TextSize = 22
Calapi = ''
```

Code for displaying label based upon result

```
    self.notehead = Label(self, font=('Helvetica', medium_text_size), fg="white", wraplength=400, bg="black", text= NoteHeading)
    self.notehead.pack(side=TOP, anchor=E)
    self.notebody = Label(self, font=('Helvetica', TextSize),justify=RIGHT, fg="white", wraplength=400, bg="black", text= NoteContent)
    self.notebody.pack(side=TOP, anchor=E)
```

If the user then logs into the companion application and updates their area to active the program has to be restarted for changes to take effect. Is it possible to re run the query periodically and change the label dynamically when the variable updates? if so how is this achieved?

Comment: `root.after(miliseconds, function_name)` - see example [using "after" to update current time](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

Comment: Thank you,

so if I understand correctly I have to define the sql query as a function and then insert that command at the bottom of the function? 

Sorry I'm very novice to Python so struggling to get my head around some of what I want to do.

Comment: you have to create "function" which gets data from database and updates elements in GUI, and then put `after()` at the end of this "function" (with name of this "function" as second argument) to execute this "function" again and again. You have to once execute this "function" and it will loop. And it will not freeze GUI.

Comment: Thank you again, I will have a play later and see if I can get it working.

[Link to github](https://github.com/jknapper66/SmartMirror/blob/master/smartmirror.py)

I have included a link to the github file if you could take a look I would appreciate it.